# Calculate $E[nX(1)]$ where $X(1)$ is the smallest order statistic.

Tags: statistics, solution-verification, exponential-distribution, order-statistics

***Let $X1,X2,...Xn$ be iid from $Exponential(1/θ)$. That is
$f(x) =\frac{1}{\theta}e^{(\frac{-1}{\theta})} , x > 0 $.
Calculate $E[nX(1)]$ where $X(1)$ is the smallest order statistic.***

I found the CDF, ($F(X)$), to be $1-e^{(\frac{-x}{\theta})}$

Then:
$E[nX(1)]$ = $\\~\\$

$n*E[X(1)]$ = $\\~\\$

$n$*$[ \int_{0}^{\infty} X(1)*n[1-F(X)]^{n-1}*\frac{1}{\theta}e^{(\frac{-1}{\theta})} \,dx]$

Here, I'm using the formula for the pdf of the minimum order statistic: $ n[1-F(X)]^{n-1}*f(x)]$

After making the substitution for $F(X)$ in the integral and doing computation, I am finally left with: $n^2$*$[ \int_{0}^{\infty} X(1)*e^{(x(\frac{n}{\theta}))}\,dx]$

Which I think simplifies to $n^2*(\gamma(2)(\frac{\theta^2}{n^2}))$

Which would then simply be $\theta^2$.

Could someone please verify if my thought process is correct and whether or not there is a simpler way to solve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your solution.  The density for $X_{(1)}$ is exponential with rate $n/\theta$; i.e., $$f_{X_{(1)}}(x) = n(1 - F_X(x))^{n-1} f_X(x) = n(1-(1-e^{-x/\theta}))^{n-1} \frac{1}{\theta} e^{-x/\theta} = \frac{n}{\theta} e^{-nx/\theta}.$$ You are missing a factor of $1/\theta$ arising from the original density of a single observation $X$.

Then, you have some notational problems:  you should instead write

$$\operatorname{E}[n X_{(1)}] = n \int_{x=0}^\infty x f_{X_(1)}(x) \, dx = n \int_{x=0}^\infty x \frac{n}{\theta} e^{-nx/\theta} \, dx = \theta.$$  You should not write $X_{(1)}$ in the integrand.

Rather than performing the integration, it is simpler to note that the minimum order statistic is exponentially distributed with rate $n/\theta$, as stated above; then, its expectation is simply $\theta/n$, hence the expectation of $n X_{(1)}$ is $n (\theta/n) = \theta$.

Comment: Thank you. It seems like I made a computational error in the integral which messed me up. Just a follow up, why are we not writing  X1 in the integrand? Since we have E[X1], I thought we would have X1*f(x) in the integrand

Comment: @Jones Because the formula is $$\operatorname{E}[X] = \int_{x \in \Omega} x f_X(x) \, dx,$$ where $x$ is a variable of integration and $\Omega$ is the support of $X$.  If you insist on using $X_{(1)}$, then you would have to write $$\int_{x_{(1)} = 0}^\infty x_{(1)} f_{X_{(1)}}(x_{(1)}) dx_{(1)}$$ and that is unnecessarily verbose.